# Tikz question - Create this path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I am new about Tikz, and I am trying to develop the following in overleaf:
[image]

I have tried with this starting code but I have a lot of much problem about trying to replicate the picture.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,1) node[anchor=north east,circle,
draw]{A} -- (2,2) node[anchor=south west,
circle,draw]{B};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Have you some idea/hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning,
                shapes}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 12mm,
  start chain = going below,
     V/.style = {ellipse, draw=red, semithick, 
                 minimum width=3.4em, inner xsep=0pt, font=\small,
                 on chain},
     X/.style = {V, font=\large},
every label/.append style = {label distance=0pt, inner sep=1pt, font=\large},
 every path/.append style = {draw=cyan,-{Triangle[scale=0.8]},semithick, }
                        ]
\node (v1)  [V, label=$\nu_1$] {$\cos \nu$};                     
\node (v2)  [V, label=$\nu_2$] {$\ln \nu$};
\node (v3)  [V, label=$\nu_3$] {$\nu_{-1}\nu_0$};
\node (v4)  [V, label=$\nu_4$] {$\nu^3_0$};
%
\node(x1)   [X, label=$\nu_{-1}$, 
             left=of v2] {$x_1$};
\node(x0)   [X, label=$\nu_0$, 
             left=of $(v3.west)!0.5!(v4.west)$] {$x_1$};
%
\node(v6)   [suspend join,  V, 
             label=$\nu_6$,
             right=of v3] {$\nu_4+\nu_2$};
%
\node(v5)   [V, label=$\nu_5$,
             right=of v1 -| v6] {$\nu_1+\nu_3$};
\node(v7)   [V, label=$\nu_4$,
             right=of x0 -| v6] {$\nu_1+\nu_3$};
%
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3}
\path  (x1) -- (v\i);
    \foreach \i in {3,4,7}
\path  (x0) -- (v\i);
%
\path  (v1) -- (v5);
\path  (v2) -- (v6);
\path  (v4) -- (v6);
\path  (v6) -- (v7);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe if you put a chalkboard type background and color the vectors chalk style the result would be more realistic.

Comment: @Sebastiano, hm, i can add background color, but imitate what OP show on her/his image is a bit more complicated ... I will wait on OP respond if this is also demand.

Comment: Thanks, the code is perfect